# What is the difference between an atomic operation and critical section?, which of the two prevents context switching?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, thread-safety, context-switch

A programming language or the processor already has "default" atomic operations and we can use them as far as I understand.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between an atomic operation and critical section?

Atomic operations are instructions that guarantee atomic accesses/updates of shared (small) variables. This generally include operations like incrementation, decrementation, addition, subtraction, compare and swap (aka. CAS), exchange, logical operations (and, or, xor) as well as basic loads/stores. If you want to perform a non trivial operation that is not supported by the target platform (or one involving large variables), then you cannot use one atomic operation. This means either multiple of them is required or another mechanism should be used instead (eg. critical section, transactional memory). Note that using multiple atomic operations often makes things significantly more complex (see [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem)). On mainstream CPUs, atomic operations are generally implemented by locking cache lines of shared caches (eg. L3) so that only one thread can access to it at a time.

Critical sections are meant to protect one or multiple instructions from being executed by multiple threads at the same time. They are generally protected using a system mutex. The thread entering the critical section lock the associated mutex and unlock it when leaving the section. System mutexes cause the thread entering a critical section to wait if the associated mutex is already locked. This is generally done using a context switch (the thread is descheduled and rescheduled later).

Critical section can be efficient when the lock is very rarely already taken by another thread. Context switches can significantly impact the performance. Atomic operation are not great either when many thread perform atomic operations on it. Contention effects can make atomic accesses significantly slower (eg. spin locks). This is especially true for atomic CAS operations. Some platform can execute atomic operation very quickly (eg. GPUs) since they have dedicated units to execute atomic operation efficiently.

> which of the two prevents context switching?

None of the two prevent context switching. Modern operating systems can perform a context switching at any time. That being said, critical section generally cause context switches: a thread trying to enter into a critical section already locked by another thread will typically enter in sleeping mode and be awaken by the OS scheduler when the other thread will unlock the section. Atomic operations do not impact the scheduling of the system (at least not on mainstream platforms).

---

Note that the above text is also true for processes.

Comment: hi @Jérôme Richard thanks -  "If you want to perform a non trivial operation that is not supported by the target platform (or one involving large variables), then you cannot use one atomic operation. This means either multiple of them is required or another mechanism should be used instead (eg. critical section, transactional memory)" - Do you mean that generally if a code involves more than one atomic operation it is better to "wrap" it in a critical section, for example?

Comment: This generally include operations like incrementation, decrementation, addition, subtraction, compare and swap (aka. CAS), exchange, logical operations (and, or, xor) as well as basic loads/stores - Are the atomic operations already "predefined" in the programming language or in the processor/architecture, is it something that is ALREADY PROVIDED to us and we just use? @Jérôme Richard

Comment: It is generally better to start with critical sections when there are many operations to protect or few non-trivial ones. Atomic operations can help the code to be faster (and to better control priorities) but not systematically. Writing atomic code is far from being simple. It is very easy to write wrong/non-portable codes that look fine but fail non-deterministically in very rare cases. So put it shortly: if you can use atomic operation very easily, do it, but if this is non-trivial, think twice or use a library doing it for you.

Comment: It is dependent of the programming languages. Some languages like recent version of C and C++ provide atomic primitives. C++ can use locks if the atomic operation is not supported on the target platform (eg. atomic operations on big objects). Basic atomic operations are implemented on all mainstream processor thanks to dedicated instruction. On x86-64 processors, the lock prefix can be added on some instruction so to lock the cache line and make the instruction atomic (eg. lock add). Some instruction are natively atomic like [xchg](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xchg) or cmpxchg16b.

Comment: thanks @Jérôme Richard "None of the two prevent context switching" - I've heard that atomic operations should be UNINTERRUPTED, I guess more like you say, the in interrupt is controlled by the cache and the OS/Processor manages (behind the scenes) to not interrupt them despite the context switch occurring.

Comment: Sure, atomic operations cannot be interrupted from the use point of view: they are atomic. However, that does not mean the code using them cannot be de-scheduled. The OS/hardware can interrupt the program between two instructions. An interruption may occur during an atomic operation but the processor has to do things so that this is not visible from the user point of view (ie. no side effects).

Comment: Note the OS has not information whether the user code is running atomic operation (besides performance counters): the processors is responsible for this (not the OS). In fact, the kernel threads can also use atomic operations and they can be scheduled too.

Comment: excellent @Jérôme Richard, thank you, you helped me a lot to understand interrupts and context switching in atomic operations. +2 and marked as useful answer

Comment: Thank you. I would be glade if you can mark this post as the answer if it is fine to you :) .

Answer (score 1):

Speaking only to the nomenclature question:

"Atomic" means "cannot be broken down into smaller parts." In programming, an operation performed by one thread is "atomic" (as seen from other threads) if there is no possible way for the other threads to see the operation in a half-way done state. From the point of view of other threads, it's *as if* the entire operation happened in a single instant. It either has already happened, or it hasn't happened yet. There is no in between.

As Jérôme Richard points out, modern computer hardware provides atomic operations on simple variables. We can use those to make more complex operations *seem* "atomic" from the point of view of other threads either by using the hardware atomics in tricky [*non-blocking algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm), or by using the hardware atomics in the implementation of mutex locks.

"Critical section" comes from a time before multi-threading. In operating system kernel code, and in "[bare metal](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bare-metal-programming-in-Embedded-systems)" application code, there has always been a limited form of concurrency between the main body of code and the [*interrupt handlers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler). "Critical section," back in the day, referred to a routine in the main body of code that was protected from interference by the interrupt handlers by executing it with interrupts disabled.

Systems programmers today still use "critical section" with the original meaning, but now we also sometimes say it to talk about a routine that is executed by a thread while the thread has a mutex locked.

IMO, "critical section" encourages a somewhat less useful way of thinking about mutex locks though because it's never the *code* that needs protection from interference. It's always about protecting the integrity of *shared data.* Sometimes a programmer who worries about defining *The* critical section can lose sight of the fact that there may be multiple routines in the program that all access the same shared data.

IMO, this is one place where an object-oriented style of programming shines, because it's easier to keep track of what needs to be protected if it is [*encapsulated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) in private members of some object and, can only be accessed through the object's thread-safe, public methods.

Comment: hi @Solomon Slow "because it's never the code that needs protection from interference. It's always about protecting the integrity of shared data." - You say that because a critical section protects rather a piece of code itself, but not the shared resource (variables), right? marked like useful response

Comment: @Daniel, No. A critical section only protects data. What I'm saying is that the _name,_ "critical section," draws your attention away from the data and draws it toward the code that uses the data.

Comment: I understand @Solomon Slow, but by the same token, a shared variable in a critical section is safe in that section, but other code can still access that shared variable from other code if we are not careful enough, right?

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not sure what "safe in that section" means. The general problem that we're trying to solve with mutexes is; one thread needs to update some shared variable(s), and it's important to not let other threads access any of the same variables until the job is completely done. If thread A runs in a critical section while thread B concurrently runs some _other_ function that accesses the same variables with no protection, then when B destroys the database because it saw something it didn't like, we probably won't say, "Well, thank Goodness! At least thread _A_ was safe."